# active directory and open directory

Tags: macos, authentication, active-directory, windows-server

I am working in a mixed environment of Mac OS and Windows machines, which the domain controller is Open Directory served by a Mac server. Actually, Mac and Windows both are installed on every machine and could be selected on boot time.

As a longtime problem, we could not join Windows 7 users to Open Directory domain. That's why I decided to setup an Active Directory server for Windows users and leave Open Directory for Mac users. Then the next problem was we must have each user twice in both Open Directory and Active Directory.

**My question is:** Is there a way to configure AD to relay its authentication requests to OD user database, and also load home directories from a shared point on the network?

Answer (score 0):

An Open Directory can be used as PDC or a BDC and yes you can replicate active directory into your Open Directory server. once that is said, setting up a new Open Directory BDC is not a question of two lines of code. I'll suggest you to read the following:

http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1180/en_US/OpenDirAdmin_v10.6.pdf

you may find more than you are looking for. :)